# Running OPENVPN client (through VPN ISP) with Apache Webserver on 443 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: iptables, openvpn, nextcloud

I am quite new to this forum and also VPN and it is really quite confusing for me. and I have tried to figure this out while googling until 4am and still no viable solution. I hope this is allowed in this forum seeing it is more than OPENVPN related. I see there is a post by @Razzak and that is EXACTLY the issue I have, except I did not use his link to SU answer (it doesnt work as option they use no longer exist). [How to make Apache output packets through a certain network interface when connected to VPN?](https://serverfault.com/questions/794887/how-to-make-apache-output-packets-through-a-certain-network-interface-when-conne)

However by following the example, I still cannot make it work as outlined by @Nath and there is no option to PM anyone. So please accept my apology by posting this again and hopefully someone can help me out with a bit more step by step instructions. I understood from the post that you needed to create 2 separate connections on the Eth0 port (in my case enp0s25) but not sure what I went wrong and I would also need it to be permanent to be in /etc/network/interfaces once it is working through command line. And also, not sure when @Razzak said about "lo" loop interface and how I can implement that to make it work.

I have Zorin 12 16.04 and Nextcloud 12 and I could access my nextcloud server inside and outside my network.i.e. sample.ignorelist.com/nextcloud with SSL enabled so it is listening on port 443 and not 80

Now the next step is I have access to TigerVPN (not advertising for them at all!) and I used openvpn --config GB London.ovpn for that matter - script below

```
client  
remote lon.tigervpn.com 1194 udp  
remote lon.tigervpn.com 443 tcp-client  
pull  
auth-user-pass   
comp-lzo adaptive  
ca ca.crt  
dev tun  
tls-client  
script-security 2  
cipher AES-256-CBC  
mute 10  

route-delay 5  
redirect-gateway def1  
resolv-retry infinite  

dhcp-renew  
dhcp-release  
persist-key  
persist-tun  
remote-cert-tls server  
mssfix
```

Since I activated OPENVPN as client, I can no longer access nextcloud inside and outside the network once cron update the IP address via FREEDNS (free domain). And Webserver / nextcloud and OpenVPN are all running on one machine (purpose for VPN is to run torrent on the same machine)

So let me try and draw a picture here below - (name and IP has been changed)

Nexcloud Server (Internal 1.0.0.3) --> Router (Gateway 1.0.0.1) --> External DYN IP by ISP (111.222.111.222) --> TigerVPN London Server (185.20.99.139) --> IP by TigerVPN (185.20.99.199) --> FREEDNS IP (Without VPN 111.222.111.222 and with VPN activated 185.20.99.199)

Routing with VPN activated -

```
root@mypc:/home/mypc# ip route list  
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.199.11.1 dev tun0  
default via 1.0.0.1 dev enp0s25  proto static  metric 100   
10.199.11.0/24 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.199.11.8   
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.199.11.1 dev tun0  
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s25  scope link  metric 1000   
185.20.99.199 via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s25  
1.0.0.0/24 dev enp0s25  proto kernel  scope link  src 1.0.0.3  metric - - 100  


root@HTPC:/home/htpc# ifconfig  
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:37:48:2e:46    
          inet addr:10.0.0.3  Bcast:1.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0  
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:37ff:fe48:2e46/64 Scope:Link  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
          RX packets:469087 errors:0 dropped:46 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:229122 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000   
          RX bytes:167072663 (167.0 MB)  TX bytes:30424651 (30.4 MB)  
          Interrupt:16 Memory:d0300000-d0320000   

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback    
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0  
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host  
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1  
          RX packets:4450 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:4450 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1   
          RX bytes:567305 (567.3 KB)  TX bytes:567305 (567.3 KB)  

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.199.11.8  P-t-P:10.199.11.8  Mask:255.255.255.0  
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
          RX packets:41 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:101 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100   
          RX bytes:15028 (15.0 KB)  TX bytes:15266 (15.2 KB)
```

while rest of the PC on the same network would use External IP set by ISP 111.222.111.222 to access the internet and so on. And I understand it makes perfect sense if VPN is deactivated and all the network will run as the traffic all go through router gateway 1.0.0.1. The question is... what can I do to change the routing or forwarding with VPN up and running so it can direct the traffic and understood by my Apache2 / nextcloud?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please use the formatting tools to make your post readable.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didnt quite know how to do it but it should be fine now

Comment: Are you sure your VPN provider allows inbound connections?

Comment: How your Real IP configured?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen - I managed to set it up and using Razzak post (it has to do something with internal routing and not external) and also I managed to have my ASUS router using their own DDNS server (therefore my DDNS server IP will always MATCH the ISP IP)... while I am running OPENVPN via my desktop (apache / cloud server). Not sure what went wrong this morning as previously it all worked.

Comment: @AlexanderT can you be more specific?

Comment: The configuration of your `enp0s25` interface is clearly messed up. And chances are it was messed up before you even brought up the VPN client. I would restart the machine and then post the output of `ip route` and `ifconfig` both before and after bringing up the VPN client.